# Utilizando itexSharp en asp.net ¿cual es la mejor forma de manejar un PDF, creándolo o rellenando un formulario?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Bueno haré uso de itexSharp para manejar documentos PDF, y con el puedo ya sea crear o utilizar documentos pdf e incluso convertir HTML en documento PDF.

¿Pero cual sería la forma más flexible de trabajar? 
Cada vez que descarguen un documento, ¿es mejor tener una clase que cree los campos o solo leer un documento y insertarlos?

Por cierto, el documento es para descargar desde una llamada XMLHttpRequest y no para visualizar en pantalla

Answer (score 1):

**>>¿es mejor tener una clase que cree los campos o solo leer un documento y insertarlos?**

Depende del diseño del documento, si es es algo complejo quizas tener un pdf prediseñado seria una buena alternativa, en este pdf prediseñador podrias ubicar campos en determiandas posiciones donde completarias con al info que recibesdesde la pagina web

[Fill in PDF Form Fields Using the Open Source iTextSharp DLL](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fill-in-pdf-form-fields-using-the-open-source-itextsharp-dll/)

Analiza cmo se utiliza el `SetField()` para asignar el valor en el lugar que determinas para ubicar el valor

**>>el documento es para descargar desde una llamada XMLHttpRequest**

La forma en como se obtenga el documento no afecta como lo generes